# What are the consequences of mixing Ferric Chloride Solution, distilled vinegar, baking soda and water?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, safety

I was attempting to etch and blade with a ferric chloride solution. I did not have enough so I filled a glass with vinegar and water (3 parts vinegar to 1 part water) then added 2 oz. of ferric chloride solution. I added baking soda later to neutralize the ferric chloride solution, but was met with a deep red foam. I quickly added more baking soda and flushed the solution down a deep sink in my basement. I rinsed out the sink and glass with water and continued to add baking soda to neutralize any ferric chloride solution that had been spread by the red foam. What reaction occurred and is this and do I need to worry about it?

Comment: Adding baking soda to anything acidic like vinegar has this effect, releasing gaseous carbon dioxide. Ferric chloride is there for the color. Additionally, it forms gel of ferric hydroxide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the red salt you are seeing is Iron (III) carbonate, which was likely created from, as you noted, the neutralization of aqueous Iron (III) chloride with Baking Soda (in excess?) per the reactions:

$\ce{FeCl3 (aq) + 3 NaHCO3 (aq)-> 3 NaCl (aq) + 2Fe(HCO₃)₃(aq)}$

$\ce{2Fe(HCO₃)₃ (aq) → Fe₂(CO₃)₃ (s) + 3H₂O (l) + 3CO₂ (g)}$

$\ce{2Fe(HCO₃)₃ + HAc (aq) → Fe₂(Ac)₃ (s) + 3H₂O (l) + 3CO₂ (g)}$

where the last reaction could also lead to Iron (III) acetate from the vinegar presence, which is also subject to further neutralization by the Baking Soda.